# what does the following code snippet mean

Tags: c++, private

I have a class named BridgeChannel. It has some things under the private sections. I don't know what they do.

```
private:

  BridgeChannel (const BridgeChannel &);
  BridgeChannel &operator = (const BridgeChannel &);
```

Your ideas and knowledge is greatly apprecitated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are `private`. This way objects of type `BridgeChannel` cannot be copied or assigned outside of `BridgeChannel`.

This is useful if your class contains some resource which is impossible, too costly, or nonsensical to copy.

In C++11 this idiom has been replaced by marking those functions as `= delete`, which serves the same purpose but provides clearer error messages.

An old helper to simplify this idiom is to inherit from `boost::noncopyable`.